# What to do if average gas usage increased by 30x but they say there is no leak?

Tags: flooring, kitchens, leak, gas

Not sure if this is the right place, but figured you guys may have some answers/suggestion of what to do?

My average hourly gas usage has increased by 30x suddenly and the company said they will send someone to check the meter in a few days...they don't consider it an emergency because I don't smell gas or see a damaged pipe.

My appliance usage has remained the same. We have only a fireplace which has only had the pilot on since the winter and never turned the actual fire on.. And a water heater that has had the temp set the same and we haven't used additional hot water over the norm.

Here is the chart of their readings/estimates and the readings I started taking last night after looking at the bill.

[image]

Comment: Have a technician check the water heater and fireplace; one may be malfunctioning. Make sure you don't have a dripping tap or shower or leak wasting hot water. How is your house heated?

Comment: What caused the large increase in August when your monthly usage was 7 times higher than usual?

Comment: @Johnny no clue... That was why I started checking (got the bill late). We haven't used the two gas appliances any more than we have the past 5-6 months, certainly not 7-8x more... I thought maybe a slow leak/malfunctioning appliance, gas company suggest maybe faulty meter and will send someone to check.. If it's an appliance where is the extra gas going? into the air?

Answer (score 4):

If you're worried about a gas leak, and the gas company cannot come out fast enough. The local fire department should have the equipment to detect a leak, and should be more than happy to come out and take some readings. Preventing a gas explosion, is much easier than dealing with the aftermath.

Comment: Yeah, that's what my sister suggested. Strangely, the last 3 measurements used barely anything... I suppose it ludicrous to think the company was rolling the meter faster than normal then stopped when I called in... But what could explain such high readings and then suddenly gone back to normal?  Will keep an eye on it for a while now..

Answer (score 0):

You could have a plumber do the same pressure test on the system that's done when the system is initially installed and inspected.